# Why does it take a long time to drop a function based index in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, index, oracle-10g, functions

I have a function based index that takes 25 minutes to create on a table of 94 Million rows.

When I drop the index, it takes 18 minutes.

Why does it take so long? I would have thought the drop would have been almost immediate? I have noticed that after ~10 minutes, the index is removed from user_indexes, but the script still executes for another ~8 minutes.

The table is partitioned, and this is an Oracle 10g RAC install. If any more information would help, I can add it as required.

Any light shed on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suspect that your statement is simply waiting for a lock on the table.

Comment: According to this: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=541834 I would have expected a resource busy error if it was locked? Also, I have another index which is similar, and if I try to drop both at the same time, I do get that error while dropping the second index. This implies to me that the "drop index" has got the lock it requires, and is just taking its time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [function-based index adds a virtual column](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/no_fbi.html) to the table (This column is then indexed). Dropping the index removes the virtual column, which leads to a cleanup that takes time (same amount of work as the removal of a non-virtual column).

Comment: asktom link: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:667694821129#70256318911496

Comment: All those years I believed Oracle was putting the expression into the index. I never knew they were implemented as hidden virtual columns.

Comment: Ditto on the lack of knowledge on the virtual columns. Thanks very much for the answer!